# How to find posterior of global parameter over many datasets? Is my method valid?

Tags: inference, markov-chain-montecarlo

Let us say I have 100 objects, and for each one I have a dataset with 50 data points. Each object's dataset can be modelled with 2 free parameters, let's say P1 and P2. On top of this, there's a single global parameter P3 that parameterises the theory.

So, all in all, I have 201 free parameters (2 x 100 + 1), on a dataset $\mathcal{D}$ with 5000 points. Doing a global posterior exploration with MCMC is too costly, as there are too many dimensions and each iteration is computationally expensive.

How then do I get a marginal posterior distribution $\mathcal{P}(\mathrm{P3}|\mathcal{D})$ for P3?

My current approach is to take a grid of 20 values for P3. Impose each one in turn, and at each one perform individual 2 parameter MCMC explorations of each object, and then find the maximum-posterior point in the chain. I then multiply together the likelihoods of all of these 100 points to get a global likelihood $\mathcal{L}(\mathcal{D}|P3)$. I cycle through the 20 values for P3 and each time calculate this global likelihood. This distribution can then be converted into a posterior via Bayes' theorem. Is this approach valid?